# Predefined users on devices

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, intune

Hello in my job we have alot of branches and users. I want to make some profiles in Intune where each branches has predefined profiles ( with programs and policies ) same for users. They will login with a domain profile that is defined in Azure AD.

Comment: I would suggest you to please refer this documentation for more information: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/device-profile-create

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can create predefined device-based profiles in Intune based on branch offices. For that, I would suggest you create user and device groups according to the branch office location and organize the users and devices in them as per their assigned branch office. Once, that has been done successfully, then would suggest you create various device configuration profiles according to the branch offices and their required configuration settings as expected in them and assign these device configuration profile to the respective user and device group in their branch offices.

•   These configuration settings will then reflect in those devices which are assigned to these branch locations. Once done, then change the primary user of those devices using a powershell script or through Intune management portal as there is no provision in Intune to predefine the user to be signed in on a device. Thus, you can either configure the last signed in user to be the primary user of that Intune managed device through a powershell script in a bulk operation or change it through the Intune Management portal.

For more information on the above, please refer to the documentation links below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/device-profile-assign

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/remote-actions/find-primary-user

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/device-profile-create